# Setting printer paper size in VB.Net for rdlc report

Tags: vb.net, printing, report, rdlc

I built a report with a landscape orientation using VB.net 2010  and made the ​​size 16.5 cm * 8.25 cm

When you print the report directly shows the size of the page A4 !!!

I need to provide the printer with a custom paper size. How can I make my report have a custom paper size?

Link: http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1379145264

Answer (score 8):

In order to change the default format (A4) of a report, you must change the report properties to accept a custom paper size.

### Set PaperSize By GUI

**Step 1**

Open your report and right click (on the gray pane, not the report itself) to select "Report Properties"

[image: Report Properties]

**Step 2**

Choose Landscape for your orientation and select a **custom** paper size. Specify your width and height as well.

[image: Paper size]

---

### Programmatically Set PaperSize

1. Paper Size should be the size in inches multiplied by 100
2. Width: The width of the paper, in hundredths of an inch
3. Height: The height of the paper, in hundredths of an inch

Here is the code I used to programmatically set a custom paper size to my report

```
ReportViewer1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 650, 325)
```

**Note: Don't forget, you may need to use the code `ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()` if it doesn't  work.*

For more information, visit [MSDN's PaperSettings.PaperSize page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize.aspx)

Comment: Thanks
Did it
But this is not what I want to do
I want to give an order that the printer paper size is 16.5 cm * 8.25 cm before print.

Comment: If you have those settings set, the printer will automatically accept it as a custom paper size and print it in that format (if it can).

Comment: Thank you Alex
But I want do that by VB.Net code.
I need customize printer setting (paper size) by code from my program..
Please download the sample project and try to help me
http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1379145264

Comment: Can you please help me with this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633350/how-to-show-report-data-in-center-of-rdlc-report

Comment: Helped a lot...  ..+1

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting the report properties - setting up page size by inches, after that setting up the width 3.0in and height 8.3in
the problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Dim page As XmlElement = AddElement(reportSection, "Page", Nothing)

```
        'landscape
        AddElement(page, "PageHeight", "8.5in")
        AddElement(page, "PageWidth", "11in")
```