# how to design and print rdlc report as receipt?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, rdlc

I'am working on printing a reciept using rdlc report in a windows forms application so I am facing a trouble with desinging the rdlc report to be printed in a small reciept paper. Somebody help me please and thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting printer paper size in VB.Net for rdlc report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799640/setting-printer-paper-size-in-vb-net-for-rdlc-report)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting the report properties size in inches after the set up the width 3.5in and height 8.3in finally setting up page regle and putting the required data into the report.